# Byte compilation still happening when `no-byte-compile` is t on adding advice

Tags: byte-compilation, advice

In org-mode, I have the following:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results scalar
(setq no-byte-compile t)
(defun f ())
(defun g ())
(add-function :before (symbol-function 'f) 'g)
(symbol-function 'f)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: #[128 "\300\301\"\210\300\302\"\207" [apply g (lambda nil nil) nil] 4 nil]
```

I wanted to see what adding advice did to the function. Why is byte compilation happening, despite `no-byte-compile` being t? How do I prevent byte compilation in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is byte compilation happening...?

Strictly speaking no byte-compilation is happening, from the looks of it.

`advice--make-1` actually generates byte code directly via `make-byte-code`.

This is obviously a low-level approach, and offhand I'm surprised to see that going on outside of compilation; but perhaps it's more common than I imagine -- I have little knowledge in this area.